# ¿Como hacer un procedimiento almacenado en postgresql para login?

Tags: postgresql, login, stored-procedure

Este es mi modelo de db en cuestion de usuarios
[image: Este es mi modelo de db en cuestion de usuarios]

Resulta que necesito que con las mismas credenciales el usuario se pueda logear, la intención es crear un procedimiento donde al servidor le devuelva sus datos de usuario, y de docente y administrativo si lo es, el dilema es que un usuario puede ser docente en varias instituciones, o administrativo en varias, o ser docente y administrativo en diferentes instituciones. Cual seria su solución? ¿En que lenguaje estaría el procedimiento? No importa el tipo de dato que devuelva, con tal de que se pueda usar en el server.

Comment: Uso mysql solo para el modelado y asi guiarme, pero la db esta en Postgresql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deberías utilizar dos consultar

1. Una consulta para al autenticación
2. Una consulta para seleccionar la institución (autorización)